# how to get sentences from words found in tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

Given a list of words as keys and list of sentences as values, how retrieve sentence for word in keys.

```
for k,v in a_tuple:
    for key in k:
        for value in v:
            if key in value:
               print(value)
```

Comment: How is the variable *a_tuple* defined?

Comment: problem already solved. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `vc_tuple = (([...], [...]), (...))` is not a dictionary, it is a tuple of tuples containing 2 lists each (with the rightmost paranthesis missing in your question). You never turn it into a `dict` either, and it would be impossible, as [lists cannot be keys in a dictionary in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Using a small example variable of the same format (containing some corner cases):

```
ex_tuple = ((["a", "b", "c"], ["b x y a z", "c w q."]), (["d", "e"], ["x y, e, d", "e f g", "a"]))
```

you can search, within each tuple, for each key in the list of keys within each value in the list of values as follows:

```
for pair in ex_tuple:
   k_lis, v_lis = pair  # assuming each tuple in your tuple contains two elements (key-value pairs)
   for k in k_lis:
     for v in v_lis:
        if k in v:
           print(f"{k} is in {v}")
```

Comment: As I understand, you are looking for which sentence contains which word. In this case, you could replace the for loop looping over v_lis (list of sentences) with something like `for index_sentence, sentence in enumerate(v_lis)`, then use `index_sentence` to keep track of the sentence.